# Wildfly log files are not overwritten once max-backup-index is reached

Tags: java, wildfly

I've set 'max-backup-index' and 'rotate-size' attributes in log config ( added below) in wildfly standalone.xml
Problem is when 'max-backup-index' is reached, wildfly keep s writing into server.log , it doesn't rotate even if its size exceed beyond 'rotate-size'.
( Have kept low values for attributes for testing)

Following configuration created 6 files with index of size around 1KB to 2 KB and after that server.log is now 1MB and still, its not rotating.

This is wildfly 9.0.2

If I restart, it continues to write logs in server.log which has already crossed rotate-size limit.

```
<size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true" rotate-on-boot="true">
       <formatter>
       <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
       </formatter>
       <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
       <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
       <append value="true"/>
       <rotate-size value="1K"/>
       <max-backup-index value="6"/>
 </size-rotating-file-handler>
```

Comment: I changed the date of my machine to next day and then file got rotated, so it seems wildfly continues to write into server.log file even if it has crossed rotate-size limit for that day and max-backup-index nuber of files is already reached. But at that time it created more than 6 ( my max-backup-index value) files, it should have deleted oldest files. Now I've 11 files at this moment, in logs folder.

Comment: <append value="false"/> and removing <suffix> solved the problem.