# How to set max history log file on Quarkus?

Tags: logging, jboss, maven-3, quarkus

I'm building an application with Quarkus 2.7, and I'm using log files.

My quarkus log file rotation settings are as follows:

```
# Configure rotation.
# The maximum file size of the log file after which a rotation is executed.
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-file-size=1M
# The maximum number of backups to keep.
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-backup-index=10
#File handler rotation file suffix. When used, the file will be rotated based on its suffix. Example fileSuffix: .yyyy-MM-dd
quarkus.log.file.rotation.file-suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd.gz
# Indicates whether to rotate log files on server initialization. You need to either set a max-file-size or configure a file-suffix for it to work.
quarkus.log.file.rotation.rotate-on-boot=true
```

Is there any setting to define the maximum number of files in the folder? or to delete old files? Or perform a purge?

Spring has the following configuration:

```
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=20
```

With this configuration there are always 20 files in the logs folder. Is there something similar in quarkus?

Comment: ```quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-backup-index``` is for that isnt it ?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49639860/597657